# Disable swipe feature in iphone

Tags: ios, angularjs

does anyone knows how to disable the swipe forward and backward feature in ios.
I am using angularjs and stuck in a problem where user can swipe back and forward this disturbs my functionality of the app. any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: are u asking for screen edge panning,which is used to move to previous controller?

Comment: Preena, I think this can't be done at application level

Comment: @muku: yes ur ryt im asking about that.

Comment: @bobleujr: any way to prevent this??

Comment: that can be done in app,u have to right in Obj-C

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish exactly what you are trying to do. I have run into this issue as well - where I need to save some piece of data before the user goes back to a previous view controller. Reacting to a button tap is easy with an IBOutlet and some simple logic. But when the user has the ability to swipe to go back with functionality built into UINavigationControllers, it's not so cut and dry now.

Instead of trying to swim against the current, why not use this new ability?

Using viewWillDisappear, check if the current view controller is no longer in `self.navigationController`'s stack. If it isn't than we are *Oscar Mike* to a different view controller and you should save your data.

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {

        [self saveImportantData];
    }

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

}
```

While I'm sure this isn't what you asked for, maybe it is a workaround that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

if u have the access to viewcontroller file,then u can use the above code to disable the screen panning

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
  }
}
```